# how to open desktop node link shared on facebook onto mobile device (mobile website version)

Tags: 7, mobile-tools

I have a desktop link:
mysite.com/node/22

When I share this link onto facebook, and try to open it on desktop prowser it's work good.

But when I try to open it (from facebook) onto mobile it's back me to webiste (mobile version) home.
mobi.mysite.com

how can i make it on mobile go to
mobi.mysite.com/node/22

I use ([mobile switch](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_switch)) and ([mobile tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_tools)) modules, and they are works good

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple, I just don't see it.

its in advanced sitting for mobile switch module, Multisite shared content must be checked.

[image]